# Is it true that $f(a+x)-f(x)$ is bounded for any $a$ if $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I can think of a counter-example that when $f(x)=x$, then $f(a+x)-f(x)=a$ is not bounded as $a$ is getter larger and larger. 
But what if I only require the bound to be independent of $x$?

Can I use extreme value theorem to say that there exists $x_0\in [x,x+a]$ such that $f(x)<f(x_0)$  on $[x,x+a]$.
In this way, we have $|f(x+a)-f(a)|<2|f(x_0)|$
But the problem is that $x_0$ may implicitly depends on $x$, so I am confused.

Comment: The MVT only applies to differentiable functions. Why don't you unpack the definition of uniformly continuous? But in any case, the problem is asking for any fixed $a$. It's wanting to know if $f(a+x)-f(x)$ is bounded in terms of $x$.

Comment: @RobertWolfe I could be missing something, but I don't think it's as simple as applying the definition. Certainly, if there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that the corresponding $\delta$ satisfies $a < \delta$, then $f(x + a) - f(x)$ will be bounded for that particular $a$. But, what if there is an $a$ where this is not the case? What if $\delta$ cannot be chosen to be larger than, say, $1$, regardless of how large $\varepsilon > 0$ becomes?

Comment: The $a$ is fixed in the problem and doesn't change. This is like saying $f(2+x)-f(x)=2$ might not be bounded (in $x$) because $2$ could be a bigger number. It's out of left field and irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: When you say bounded for any $a$ I would take that to mean that if someone gives you an $a$ you can put a bound on $f(a+x)-f(x)$ that holds for any $x$.  Your example of $f(x)$ satisfies this.  If I give you $a$, you can say that $f(a+x)-f(x)$ is bounded by $1.1|a|$, for example.

Comment: @RobertWolfe I'm not convinced you're understanding me here. Why not write an answer? It's difficult to unpack your thoughts with any specificity based only on a hint.

Answer (score 3):

By definition of uniform continuity, there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<1$
whenever $|x-y|<\epsilon$. There is $N\in\Bbb N$ with $|a/N|<\epsilon$.

Now prove that $|f(x+a)-f(x)|<N$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be concrete here, and let me show that $g(x):=f(1+x)-f(x)$ is a bounded function in $x$.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there is a positive real number $\delta$ such that for every pair of real numbers $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the inequality $|y-x|<\delta$, we may assert that
$$|f(y)-f(x)|<1\,.$$

Now choose a natural number $n$ so that $0<1/n<\delta$. Then, regardless of $x$, we can say that
$$|f(x+1/n)-f(x)|<1\,.$$

Which in turn implies that, for any $x$, we can say
\begin{align*}|f(x+2/n)-f(x)|&=|f(x+2/n)-f(x+1/n)+f(x+1/n)-f(x)|\\&\leq |f(x+2/n)-f(x+1/n)|+|f(x+1/n)-f(x)|\\&<1+1\\&=2
\end{align*}
This reasoning could be evidently expanded. By induction, we can show
$$|f(x+k/n)-f(x)|<k$$
for any natural number $k$. In particular,
$$|f(x+1)-f(x)|<n\,.$$

Thus, $g(x)$ is a bounded function: $|g(x)|<n$ for all $x$. But there's nothing special about the number $1$. Replace it with $a$ or $|a|$ where appropriate to get an argument.